# apache rewrite rule for single query string

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want Apache to rewrite

```
http://example.com/index.html?page=123
```

as

```
http://example.com/page123.html
```

I tried this

```
RewriteRule  ^page([^/\.]+).html index.html?page=$1 [L]
```

I got this:

```
"page123.html?page=1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I worked hard and found out this solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index.html /page%1.html? [L,R=301]
```

Demo: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=d254c756-69af-5905-bb29-9741e15dd4cb

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this for a 301 redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^index.html /page%1.html [L,R=301]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=3ceeba11-dc2c-535c-8e72-425bc282c514

If you want to mask http://example.com/index.html?page=123 as http://example.com/page123.html do this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+).html /index.html?page=$1 [L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=f56d1393-9302-5148-be22-107df8b67aba

Comment: Problem with this is that it still includes the query on the end of the re-written URL. If you include `?` on the end of the RewriteRule it will stop the query from being added. Then it works perfectly :) - `RewriteRule ^index.html /page%1.html? [L,R=301]`